# StrutsSpringTestCase - Several contexts - How to instantiate them properly in order

Tags: java, spring, junit, struts2, actioncontext

I am writing integration test cases for the project that uses Struts2, Spring, Hibernate using JUnit.

My test class extends `StrutsSpringTestCase`. The application needs login/session to invoke any action. Following is the code:

```
@Test
public void testGetActionProxy() throws Exception {
    
    ActionProxy proxy;
    String result;
    ActionContext.getContext().setSession(createUserSession()); // Not sure if this is needed here. But in order to get the session working, I need this.

    proxy = initAction("cInfo");
    assertNotNull(proxy);
        
    CustInfo action = (CustInfo) proxy.getAction();
    result = proxy.execute();
    assertEquals(Action.SUCCESS, result);
}
```

The `initAction()` method:

```
private ActionProxy initAction(String actionUri) {
    ActionProxy proxy = getActionProxy(actionUri);
    
    ActionContext.setContext(proxy.getInvocation().getInvocationContext());  // I tried this line of code to get the ServletActionContext.getMapping().getName() to work. But no use.
    
    ActionContext actionContext = proxy.getInvocation().getInvocationContext();
    actionContext.setSession(createUserSession()); // This is for setting a session
    return proxy;
 }
```

Before it hits this method, it loads all the config files. `struts.xml` `jpaContext.xml`, `beans.xml`, etc.

My Action class `CustInfo` implements `ServletRequestAware` and it has a method `getActionName` which as the line:

```
 return ServletActionContext.getActionMapping().getName();
```

This gets invoked when I call `result = proxy.execute();`. So the request is failing.

**Question 1**: Why does it return `null`? I thought `ServletActionContext` is automatically initiated, so it should return a value. But its not. If its not initialized, where is the proper place to initialize and how?

I tried the following after `getActionProxy` call. But it still did not work.

```
ServletActionContext.setContext(proxy.getInvocation().getInvocationContext());
```

**Question 2**: To set the session, before `getActionProxy()`, I am having to call,

```
ActionContext.getContext().setSession(createUserSession());
```

And again, after `getActionProxy`

```
ActionContext actionContext = proxy.getInvocation().getInvocationContext();
actionContext.setSession(createUserSession());
```

to set the session. I assume, there is something wrong here.

**Question 3**: Looks like, there are several contexts in play here:`applicationContext`, `ActionContext` `ServletContext` and `ServletActionContext`.

When my test class extends `StrutsSpringTestCase` class, I guess `applicationContext` is initialized. But I am not sure about other contexts. Where to initialize them?

**Edit:**

Further investigation in the source code reveals one issue..
When I call `ServletActionContext.getActionMapping()`, internally its calling `ActionContext`'s `get()` method.

```
public Object get(String key) {
    return context.get(key);
}
```

`context` is a map of object, in which its looking for value for a key `struts.actionMapping`, which does not exist. So, returns `null`. But not sure why it is there. It's not empty. It has other key/values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your questions:

`ServletActionContext.getActionMapping()` returns the mapping from the action context, if it's not set then you get `null`.

You shouldn't set a session manually, a session is created when action is executed.

Don't mess up different classes `ActionContext`, `ServletContext`, and `ServletActionContext`. You shouldn't do anything with initializing these objects, because it's done by the superclass `StrutsSpringTestCase`.

```
public void testGetActionMapping() {
    ActionMapping mapping = getActionMapping("/cInfo.action");
    assertNotNull(mapping);
    assertEquals("/", mapping.getNamespace());
    assertEquals("cInfo", mapping.getName());
}

public void testGetActionProxy() throws Exception {        
    ActionProxy proxy = getActionProxy("/cInfo.action");
    assertNotNull(proxy);

    CustInfo action = (CustInfo) proxy.getAction();
    assertNotNull(action);

    String result = proxy.execute();
    assertEquals(Action.SUCCESS, result);
}
```

Comment: Hmmm. The application checks for a value in a session. If it doesn't then the action won't be executed. So I am creating a session and putting in it manually. With this, it seems to take care of the "login"/"session" part, but this getActionMapping thing doesn't seemt work.

Comment: You should provide configuration for the action, i.e. in `struts.xml`.